# ColdFusion 8 Printing Issue

Tags: coldfusion

I've hit a weird snag developing a reports using ColdFuions 8. The report prints a number of large HTML tables and the customer wants them to be formated ins such a way that when they are printed out the user will get 2 of the tables per page.

So it wasn't hard to make a page break by using a

```
<p style="page-break-before: always"></p>
```

However, while I got the desired effect while using the development ColdFusion environment on my laptop, I get a diffent effect when printing reports generated on the test web server. There the reports print out with a much larger font so that the second table spills over onto a second page.

Has anyone else experienced this or has a recomendation for how to try and tackle it?

Comment: Are both browsers for the environments set to the same default font size? In general, it's left to the individual user to set their own printing preference settings - which makes a mess for us programmers.

Comment: Yes, even using my own browser. I can print one set from my environment and then call up the same page on the test environment and print and get print outs with much larger fonts. On the screen they look the same its just on the papaer that it looks so different.

Comment: Are normal web pages doing this strange larger-font-size problem in your test environment? How about other coldfusion pages?

Comment: other pages seem off too but not as dramatic

Comment: is there a stylesheet linked using the print media type on the test environment that has different font settings then your dev environment?

Comment: Its the same style sheet, thats what makes it such a crazy thing.

Comment: any differences in whitespace in application.cfm? any other code changes between live and dev?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a report needs to be printed, I would recommend using [CFDOCUMENT](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c21.html) to create a PDF. You get much more control over the final output including changing page orientation which is great for tables that are wide. It honors a lot of HTML and CSS including the page-break-before style so you shouldn't have to do to much conversion to use it outside of wrapping the report area with `CFDOCUMENT` tags. It has been available since CF7 so it should work for you on CF8.